# Is my microwave still safe to use after accidentally heating metal in it?

Tags: microwave

My small kid used a metal bowl in a microwave oven and there was a spark. I immediately switched off the oven.

There was a burnt mark on the left side of the oven. Though the microwave oven switches on (Light is one), I am not sure if it actually works.

Will the microwave oven in general work even after such spark and burnt ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The spark was a voltage jumping over a gap somewhere. This may occur again, but so long as the magnetron survives, you should be okay.  The problem with sparks is they can leave a carbon trail deep inside which is conductive and may actually make the next spark occur at a slightly lower voltage. If this happens enough, you will eventually (or shortly) damage the unit and make it unusable.

I actually work as a product safety consultant and I can say, so long as you have an approved product (CSA, UL, ETL, or TUV) this sort of fault was actually tested. You should be a safe enough and not start a fire.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't had this problem thankfully, but I would think that if it seems to function ok, then you can continue using it. After a bit of research I also found [this](http://www.mamapedia.com/article/do-i-have-to-throw-out-my-microwave):

> I accidentally put something metal in my friend's microwave about 3
>   years ago. The metal was covered in plastic so I didn't realize what I
>   was doing. The smell was really bad, but to this day, the microwave
>   works.
>
> My mom's microwave was having a problem where it would not turn off.
>   The other day, she was on the phone and forgot about it, and burned
>   something up in the microwave. Now it won't even heat water. So, she
>   had to throw her's out.
>
> I guess the microwave is okay if it still works.

AND a similar one [here](https://au.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20081201191426AAfaVgR):

> The metal isn't going to hurt the food in any way, the food should be
>   fine. As long as the microwave seems to function properly, it should
>   be ok, as well. I have accidentally left utensils in the microwave
>   before and the appliance didn't sustain damage. Damage is just a
>   possibility, not a definite occurrence.
>
> Some metals are even meant to be placed in the microwave, it depends
>   on the type and the shape. My microwave, for instance, came with a
>   metal rack that slides into the center. I think it depends partially
>   on whether or not there are flat edges on the metal, which can cause
>   sparks.
>
> Bottom line, you're ok. Just don't make leaving metal in the microwave
>   a habit. Technically it could short out or catch fire or otherwise
>   start acting up. But you'll know if that happens.

I think another good idea would be to call the manufacturer and ask them if you want to double check.

Comment: Wikipedia's got some good information on that second point: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microwave_oven#Metal_objects  The damage to the side panel was probably just caused by arcing current.  As long as it didn't short out the magnetron, you're probably okay.