# Microwave smell

Tags: equipment

A metal container was used in our Microwave,  Since then there is a burnt sort of smell in the Microwave.  The Microwave is still working well,  we need to get rid of the existing smell, also we would like to know if there is any health danger in eating food that has been heated in this Micro

Answer (score 3):

For the smell, microwave a bowl with lemons squeezed into the water.

Whether the food will be safe, yes:
[Is my microwave still safe to use after accidentally heating metal in it?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/45826/is-my-microwave-still-safe-to-use-after-accidentally-heating-metal-in-it)