# My microwave sparked

Tags: microwave, kitchen-safety

I put my mug which has a golden handle by mistake in the microwave. Then the microwave sparked so I disconnected the microwave. Is the microwave still safe to use? The microwave is only 3 months old.

Comment: It's *probably* okay.  See https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/45826/67

Comment: People melt metals in those, so as other things, they are robust enough https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=ybcdRQmQcHQ

Answer (score 2):

In the past I made such a mistake multiple times with the same microwave... the one I still use to this day.

So if the sparks from the golden part of your mug was the only incident, I believe your microwave is just fine.